# Laravel - Adapting existing methods for API

Tags: xml, api, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a current project made with Laravel and now need to create some API's so a client can communicate with our system. But I'm not sure what the best way to approach this is.

How should I approach something like this the Laravel way? With the functionality already working, I'm not sure if I should validate and adapt their requests somehow so that it fits in with the currently working code, or create another separate function altogether for handling the requests.

For the validation, I'd like to use the FormRequest or extend my own class if needed. And on validation failure, I'd like to be able to return an XML response. I already have the functions for generating the XML, but need a way to return it with the custom error messages defined in the messages() method.

Any direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the majority of your logic in Controllers, Models or else where? Do you have any automated testing for your existing code?

Comment: I have a service layer, so I have service classes that the controllers call. So the logic is in those service classes, and they receive the request object from the controllers. I do not have automated testing currently.

Answer (score 0):

So, full disclosure: I created some helpful packages when dealing with xml and apis:

- https://github.com/mtownsend5512/request-xml
- https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml

They allow you to automatically converting incoming xml into an array and merge it into the Request object so it can be validated with FormRequests if desired. You can also respond with xml, or even the requesting application's preferred format (json or xml).

Lastly, you can handle errors in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in the `render` method like so:

```
$response = [
    'status' => 'ERROR',
    'message' => 'Sorry, there was a problem completing your request.',
    'data' => [],
    'errors' => []
];
$httpCode = 400;

// Validation exception, for when the user doesn't fill something out correctly
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException) {
    $response['message'] = 'A validation error occured.';
    $response['errors'] = $exception->errors();
    $httpCode = 415;
}

// Method not allowed (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE)
if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
    $response['message'] = 'HTTP method not allowed.';
    $httpCode = 405;
}

// Clean up the no query found message (findOrFail())
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
    $response['message'] = "Sorry, we couldn't find what you're looking for. Please try again.";
    $httpCode = 404;
}

// When the user makes a request to a route with the wrong http verb
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException) {
    $response['message'] = "Oops, it looks like there was an error interacting with that resource.";
    $httpCode = 405;
}


return response()->preferredFormat($response, $httpCode);
```

Now any time your application encounters common Laravel exceptions it will return api responses in either json or xml (depending on which your requesting client prefers).